# Polymorph design when filling a map container in C++

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I'm not good at OOP design, but I need to demonstrate my knowledge to potential employer.
The situation is following:

I've got a file with parameters of key-value type, called `parameters.txt`.
I've got a `map <string, CommonParamValue>` as a container. I need to fill it with elements, using the file with parameters. The key is always a `std::string` parameter, the `CommonParamValue` can be represented with `int`, `double`, `string` and a standard function call. To implement this, the `CommonParamValue` is a base class with virtual methods. It has childs - `StringParamValue`, `DoubleParamValue`, `CurTimeParamValue`. The base class and every child have a method `virtual string GetValue()` that returns a string representation of inner data; `virtual void SetValue(string)` to set the value.

**The question is how to fill the container `map <string, CommonParamValue>` with appropriate data in runtime using polymorphism?** Now I've got such situation:

*parameters.txt*

```
*user_name=Jane
*order_number=1325
current_date=
```

*Routine for filling map*

```
ifstream in(fileParamsPath);
    if (! in)
    {
        cout << "Cannot open file with parameters, program is terminating." << endl;
        cin.get();
        exit(-1);
    }
    string key = "", value = "";
    while(in)
    {
        getline(in, key, '=');
        getline(in, value, '\n');

        // put key and value into the container
        // right here we need to analyze the data type and choose appropriate container.
        // CommonParamValue *paramValue = new DoubleParamValue(); or
        // CommonParamValue *paramValue = new CurTimeParamValue(); or
        // CommonParamValue *paramValue = new StringParamValue();

        paramValue->SetValue(value);
        params.insert(make_pair(key, *paramValue)); // params is a map <string, CommonParamValue>
        delete paramValue;
    }
    in.close();
```

There's an idea to keep the type of value-parameter in file `parameters.txt` and analyze it when filling `map <string, CommonParamValue>`

*parameters.txt*

```
*user_name=Jane
string

*order_number=1325
int

current_date=
function
```

And modify routine for filling `map <string, CommonParamValue>` this way:

```
string key = "", value = "", type = "";
    while(in)
    {
        getline(in, key, '=');
        getline(in, value, '\n');
        getline(in, type, '\n');
        in.get(); // got the dividing empty string
        // put key and value into the container
        // right here we need to analyze the data type and choose appropriate container.
        if(type == "int")
        {
            CommonParamValue *paramValue = new IntParamValue();
        }
        else if(type == "function")
        {
            CommonParamValue *paramValue = new CurTimeParamValue();
        }
        else if(type == "string")
        {
            CommonParamValue *paramValue = new StringParamValue();
        }
        else
        {
            // error
            exit(1);
        }

        paramValue->SetValue(value);
        params.insert(make_pair(key, *paramValue)); // params is a map <string, CommonParamValue>
        delete paramValue;
    }
```

Is that a good decision or bad? Maybe my potential employer wanted me to implement it in other way, but I have only this decision. Is there any better one for a junior C++ programmer?

Comment: You cannot store subclass objects in map that contains objects of base class. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing You need `boost::ptr_map` or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most classic design applicable is that of a [factory method design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

```
CommonParamValue* createParamValue( const std::string &value );
```

The `createParamValue` method takes the responsibility of creating the appropriate derived `ParamValue` and return it as a `CommonParamValue`.

You can avoid pumping additional strings for "type" into `parameters.txt` by inferring the type, inside `createParamValue`, using the value string. A [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) sounds like the most elegant for `int`, `double` and `CurTime`. [Boost regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) is an example library lets you do this in c++. But of course if you're looking for a quick solution, then writing your own 30-line decision tree should not be a problem for these simple grammars.

Answer (score 1):

The if statements in client code looks a bit iffy to me. Could try a factory class?

Have a Base Class IParamValue

```
IntParamValue : public IParamValue { }

static IParamValue * Create(string selection);

IParamValue * IParamValue::Create(string selection)
{
    if (selection == "int") return new IntParamValue();
    ...
}
```

Client code:

```
IParamValue* param = IParamValue::Create ("something");
```